# Want to close the bug in bugzilla through REST API's with proper comment

Tags: rest, bugzilla

I have a requirement to close the bug in bugzilla through REST API's with proper comments.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would suggest looking at the API documentation, in particular this section: http://bugzilla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/core/v1/bug.html#update-bug

Edit: Just `PUT /rest/bug/(id_or_alias)`

```
{
  "status" : "CLOSED",
  "resolution" : "fancy fix!"
}
```

Comment: I am able to update the bug fields for comment or bugstatus but i cannot able to do both at a time.

Comment: My requirement is "I have add comment and change the status of the bug to resolved".I have added new comment with the POST and update the bug state with PUT API's.Can i do it both at a time.

Comment: I don't think you can. What is wrong with 2 calls, one after the other?

Comment: Before closing the bug in bugzilla,Need to enter a comment.If we call separately comment added to the bug then am unable to move the status of the bug to resolved state because it is expecting a comment in bugzilla.